History of the notion of integral ring extensions?
Can anyone give me references about the history of the notion of integral ring extensions in number theory ?
The theory is nice when presented in books nowadays, but I really wonder how the number theorists of the 19th century came up with the fact that the right definition of an "integer" in a number field has to do with the notion of integral dependence on the base ring.

Chapters 16-18 of Gray's History of Abstract Algebra cover the emergence of the subject in the works of Kummer and Dedekind.

@Conifold : thank you !
